# text,date datatypes in database not reflecting from front end simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, simple-form, type-conversion

Below is part of my code which is not getting reflected in database. ":reason" is "text" datype and ":dated" is "date" datatype.

Other columns with ":string" are getting reflected in database when tested. Why is this happening ?

Regarding "date" i guess there is some change  form front end and back end formats ..dont know about text datatype. Please help me how to handle it.

```
   <%= f.input :category, :collection => ["-- Choose From List --","Member", "NMEmail", "NMCell", "Phone", "UKP", "To Myself"],
         :default => '-- Choose From List --',:input_html => { :class => 'ddown'}, :label => 'Send To' %>


      <div class="member toggle" style="display:none;" >
      <%= f.input :dated, :label => 'Date of Smile', :default => Date.today, input_html: { class: 'datepicker' } %>
      <%= f.input :reason,:input_html => { :rows => 5}, :label => "Type Your Message" %>
      </div>

<%end%>
```

Comment: what does your schema.rb file say about this table? And what information is saved instead of the wanted formats?

Comment: hi jason, everything is working fine..but my question is like how to access the columns of the saved table ? fields are populating properly in database.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In what way do you want to access the columns? Do you want to print the info in the columns to the web page?

Comment: like ...once new method and create method are are called..which means data is populated in database table w.r.t its form view. Now i want to call the mailer if @style.category == 'mailing' { where category is column name of just saved database table}.

Comment: If you want to call the mailer method after the data is saved then you can just add it to the create method in the controller